# Tenho um arquivo de select em 4 paginas em 1 delas funciona e nas outras tres nao responde a query

Tags: php, mysql

```
function recuperaRacas($idAnimal) {
        $idAnimal = strip_tags($idAnimal);
        $query = "select raca_id 'idRaca', raca 'raca' from raca_nimal where id_nimal = " .$idAnimal. " order by raca;";
        $queryBuscaRaca = $this->conexaoMysql->query($query);
        $queryBuscaRaca->execute();
        $listaRacas = array();
        while ($row = $queryBuscaRaca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $listaRacas[] = array('idRaca' => utf8_encode($row["idRaca"]),
                'raca' => utf8_encode($row["raca"]));
        }
        return $listaRacas;
    }
```

// Model

//  inicio do controller

```
case 'buscaRaca':
        $idAnimal = strip_tags($_REQUEST['idAnimal']);
        $listaRacas = $Doacao->recuperaRacas($idAnimal);
        $html = "";
        foreach ($listaRacas as $raca) {
            $html .= "<option value='" . $raca['idRaca'] . "'>" . $raca['raca'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo $html;


        break;
    }
```

// fim controller

// inicio view

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Qual a raça?</label>
                        <select class="" id="raca" name="raca">
                            <option value="">Selecione uma opcao</option>
                            <?php foreach ($listaRacas as $raca): ?>
                                <?php if ($raca['idRaca'] == $raca['idRaca']): ?>
                                    <option selected="selected" value='<?= $raca['idRaca'] ?>'><?= $raca['raca'] ?></option>";
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <option value='<?= $raca['idRaca'] ?>'><?= $raca['raca'] ?></option>";
                                <?php endif ?>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#tipo_nimal').val() != "") {
            buscarRacas();
        }
    });

    function buscarRacas() {
        var idAnimal = $('#tipo_nimal').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Controller/DoacaoController.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {action: 'buscaRaca', idAnimal: idAnimal},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#raca').empty().append(data);
            }
        });

    }


//
```

Queria lembrar que estou usando os mesmos códigos para as 4 páginas, isso pode dar alguma coisa? ou deveria popular o select nos 4 ?

Comment: Qual erro você está tendo? Alguma exception no PHP?

Comment: Então ele não me mostra nenhum erro, só não me passa o resultado no select, pra voce entender bem o que estou fazendo, estou populando um select Tipo de Animal e Aparecer as Raças desses animais, 1 View ele mostrou certinho, nas outras 3 não mostrou

Comment: Você já tentou adicionar a funcao error() ali no seu ajax? Experimente adicionar o comando: console.log(data) no inicio da funcao success() do JavaScript.

Comment: Ele me deu esse erro aqui   (buscarRacas is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange)

Comment: Ma acredito que não seja, pois esse erro daria a mesma coisa no primeiro que deu certo.

Comment: Isto é um indicativo de que não está encontrando a função javascript buscarRacas ao executar o evento onChange() do seu select. Por favor, poste o código completo do seu javascript para que possamos analisar melhor o erro.

Comment: Mas como em um ele executa e em outro ele não executa?, vamos lá eu dei um copiar e colar pra que fossem os mesmos selects nas 4 paginas, em 1 apenas funcionou, porque nas outras nao dariam certo? alguma query nao ta batendo?

Comment: Infelizmente não consigo dizer exatamente qual o problema. Mas é bem provável que o erro seja em outro ponto do código e não na geração do Select em si.

Comment: Você quer dar uma olhada no código? poderia me passar seu email se possivel? se não for incomodo, eu preciso apenas finalizar esses 4 selects e estou me debatendo a dias

Comment: o mais ideal seria você postar o minimo de código possível para identificarmos o erro. Caso não seja possível, posso apenas lhe indicar o tratamento geral de erros: colocar console.log() por toda a aplicação até encontrar o erro. Mas pelo que você comentou, tenho quase certeza que o erro é alguma função javascript que você colocou no evento onChange() deste SELECT.

Comment: Bem eu tenho ele aqui  $query = "select raca_id 'idRaca', raca 'raca' from raca_nimal where id_nimal = " .$idAnimal. " order by raca;"; seria esse o select

Comment: o Select que eu falo é do HTML. Seu código PHP me parece estar todo correto. O seu problema é código Javascript.

Comment: Eu mandei uma resposta com o Código que está certo, no qual eu copiei e colei só aquela parte final até chegar no JavaScript

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#tipo_nimal').val() != "") {
            buscarRacas();
        }
    });

    function buscarRacas() {
        var idAnimal = $('#tipo_nimal').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Controller/DoacaoController.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {action: 'buscaRaca', idAnimal: idAnimal},

            success: function (data) {
                $('#raca').empty().append(data);
            }
        });

    }   (O script ta puxando do controller)

Comment: Tentei mudar as sintaxes e tambem nao resolveu